# How to solve this vector differential equation concerning circular motion?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, vector-analysis, classical-mechanics

Let $O$ be a fixed point. A string with natural length $a$ and modulus of elasticity $\lambda$ is attached to $O$ and a particle $P$ with mass $m$, which is free to move. Let $\def\r{\mathbf r} \vec{OP}=\r$. Let $\def\i{\mathbf i}\def\k{\mathbf k} \i,\k$ be the unit vector to the right and upwards, respectively. We can derive the equation of motion
$$
m\ddot \r=-mg\k-\frac{\lambda}{a}\r+\frac{\lambda\r}{|\r|}.
$$
**Question**: can we find a general solution of this equation? I know how to find the general solution of 
$$
m\ddot \r=-mg\k-\frac{\lambda}{a}\r,
$$
but the last term is an eyesore - it makes the whole thing not linear.

Comment: Have you tried to write this with polar coordinates $(r,\theta)$ instead?

A classical trick to solve the pendulum equation is to replace $\sin \theta$ with $\theta$ since $\sin \theta \sim_{0} \theta$.

Comment: This could be a [Classical central-force problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_central-force_problem) if not for the presence of the forcing term $-mg\mathbf{k}$: I would try to find if the motion is nevertheless (hyper-)planar i.e. $\mathbf{r}$ belongs to a fixed (hyper)plane in the ambient euclidean space, and have a look to the formulas for the integration of such vector fields.